# How to load page views like header, sidebar with session data in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, view

I have created a view with the name template.php with the following code.

```
<?php  
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view($middle);
    $this->load->view('footer');    
 ?>
```

and in controller i use like

```
public function index()
    {
    $data['middle'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
    }
```

So my question is how to pass session data like  `$data['session'] = $this->session->all_userdata();` to header. 
I can pass the session data by loading each view in controller. but how in template file.?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?? If it's directly accessible from the view.

Comment: yes it is accessible but i want to pass array of session to once in header view. not in each controller function. but i don't know how to do.

Comment: You dont need to pass anything the session is already available in the view. Just passing it as an array to header view only doesnt stop it being available in other views its available anywhere that you can access a codeigniter object (ie $this). Doesnt make sense to restrict it either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't include the header and footer from the view. How I achieve this, is to extend the Controller. Like this;

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function show_view($view, $data = array())
    {
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view($view, $data);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }

}
```

Now, you can load any view, and we pass the $data array to both the header and footer too.

```
$this->show_view('homepage', $data);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In any of your views you should be able to use the session helper.

```
echo $this->session->userdata('foo');
```

Comment: It's not a **session helper**. It's session object itself accessible from a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trick like passing array of data from controller and passing inner array again in your template.php view.

```
public function index()
{
    $data['middle'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('template',array('data' => $data)); //trick to get whole data array in your template view.
}
```

then in your template view

```
<?php  
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view($middle);
    $this->load->view('footer');    
 ?>
```

Comment: it works , but is it possible to pass array of of once for header view not in each function of controller. in this case i have to pass array of data for header view in each function of controller .

Comment: Craig's answer is better solution to your problem.